# How can I insert a double type value in mongo using Groovy?

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

Iam inserting 6.4000  value in mongo and I need it to be a double but mongo stores it as Decimal

```
Document document = new Document("Target",6.4000)
```

how can i enter it as double? any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of MongoDB you're using tt should be inserted as a double by default or automatically converted to [Decimal128](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/?org/bson/types/Decimal128.html) , if you don't want the conversion you might want to explicitly declare the type like:

```
Document document = new Document("Target", new Double("6.4000"))
```

You can see [BSON to JSON data type mapping](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/bson/documents/)

additionally you can check the type of the inserted value:

```
document = collection.find(eq("Target", 6.4000)).first()
log.info('Value from the database type: ' + (document.get('Target').getClass().getName()))
```

[image]

More information: [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/)